# An error in the encoding of the Content-Disposition header (contains the Cyrillic alphabet) UWP

Tags: encoding, uwp, content-disposition

When I get the file name from the link "Ð\u0097Ð°ÐºÐ°Ñ\u0082.jpg" instead "Закат.jpg".
Determined that the file name comes in the encoding "windows-1251". When trying to convert to UTF8, UTF16. The file name continues to be displayed incorrectly. Has anyone come across something like this?

```
                            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
                            Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
                            Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
                            byte[] wind1252Bytes = wind1252.GetBytes(FileName);
                            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8, wind1252Bytes);
                            string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Comment: Hello, how did you get `FileName`? From your code, it is already a string variable that has been read. During the process of reading it, has there been any encoding conversion? For example, the source file is a web page file, you can try to read the byte array of the file directly, instead of reading the file content as a string and then encoding, because in the process of converting the file into a string, the encoding may be has changed

Comment: `'Закат'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')` _python_ code  shows a  mechanism how do you get your garbled [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) string ```'Ð—Ð°ÐºÐ°Ñ‚'```.

Comment: FileName is a string

Comment: Hi, can you provide a more complete code to show your acquisition process? (if you define the value of `FileName` directly in the code, it will not be win1252 encoded). And does the problem occur only in UWP?

Comment: Hi, FileName get from httpRequest(Content Disposition)

Comment: Hello, when getting `HttpContentDispositionHeaderValue.DispositionType` has been converted into a string, its encoding may have changed

Comment: Richard Zhang, probably yes.